# Как "протащить" пайплайн через несколько процессов?

Tags: linux, bash, pipelines, stdin

Надо вытащить с лога записи за последние несколько минут. Написал `bash`-скрипт для этого:

```bsh
d=$(date --date='5 min ago' '+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'); echo $d; tac log.log | (while read -r line; do ([[ $line =~ (^[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}) && $d > $line ]] && (break)) || echo $line; done;) | tac -
```

Закладывал такую логику:

1. Читаем файл с конца
2. Дочитываем до какой-то определенной строки.
3. Вывод из 2 передаём обратно в `tac`, чтобы "перевернуть" вывод
   обратно.

Но `break` здесь не выполняется (захватываются лишние строки). `bash` я знаю очень плохо, как удалось нагуглить, причина в том, что с помощью `|` "плодятся" процессы и по факту в цикл попадает несколько потоков. Решением здесь будет передавать пайплайн через `<`. Вот тут возникли проблемы. Не совсем понимаю, как это сделать.
Пробовал такие варианты:

```bsh
d=$(date --date='5 min ago' '+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'); echo $d; tac <(while read -r line; do ([[ $line =~ (^[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}) && $d > $line ]] && (break)) || echo $line; done;) <tac <log.log
```

Получаю `tac: No such file or directory`.

```bsh
d=$(date --date='4 min ago' '+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'); echo $d; { tac | (while read -r line; do ([[ $line =~ (^[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}) && $d > $line ]] && (break)) || echo $line; done;) | tac } < log.log
```

Тут процесс вообще блокируется.

Comment: `journalctl` — это умеет, зачем вам bash?

Comment: @0andriy Система, на которой это будет делаться, находится в очень жёстких рамках. Если `journalctl` по умолчанию нет в `Linux`, то возможности его поставить не будет.

Comment: я уже советовал журнал) а journalctl по умолчанию есть в Linux, разве что у медиков древний центос всё ещё в проде.

Comment: @МихаилМуругов а что есть на сервере? может скриптовый язык пхп или питон или хотяб луа? я бы эту задачу решал так: запускаем сервис, который будет читать файл как `tail -f` и там набивать строки в ttl cache. по сигналу hup сбрасывать кеш в файл. тут кода на 10 строк и нагрузки почти ноль.

Comment: @eri `journalctl` в конечной системе, как оказалось, имеется, но с системы есть возможность только читать. Прав на запись крайне мало, т.е. как-то настроить там `journalctl` не получится. Вообще, эта задача вытекла из задачи получить логи с определённого времени. В [той задаче](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1116432/324059) проблемой является то, что некоторые логи могут быть разбиты на несколько строк.

Comment: а по скриптовым языкам? питон есть? какой версии?

Comment: если надо за последние минуты, то и настраивать особо не нужно.

Comment: @eri `Python 2.7.5`. Закинуть скрипт на сервер тоже не получится, а передавать его одной строкой получится очень громоздко... Оценочно, логи надо будет получать за последние 10 минут, 2 минуты, 10 секунд.

Comment: `sed` есть в доступе? `sed -n '/patern/ ,$p' logfile` выдаст от патерна до конца файла. Формат времени лога такойже, как и в вопросе?

Comment: @Hellseher `sed` есть. Формат времени такой же.